# Best way to identify 'most notable' increases (or decreases) amongst a large number of categories where the volumes are low?

Tags: predictive-models

I have a large number of categories (on the order of 1,000), measured by month, and I would to identify a few dozen of the categories which have the 'most notable' (I realize this is a ambiguous term) increases/decreases in the most recent month relative to past history. I don't need to make any predictions, rather just a reproducible way to callout notable changes in the most recent month as a high level 'these might be notable, let's callout for potential further review'.

The categories themselves have a large variety in average volume (some categories have thousands of instances per month, others have zero more often than not). Given this volume difference I don't see having a 'one size fits all' approach, so my current approach is to:

- Break down the categories into quartiles based on volume
- Within each quartile, look for the largest (absolute value) modified Z-score
- Report on the top N modified Z-scores per quartile as the 'top movers' for the month

Although this is not a robust approach, I think it meets the needs largely for the kind of high level identification that I need (I have used more robust methods, like ARIMA, but I don't think the juice is worth the squeeze here).

The main downside here is that hundreds of my low volume categories have a MAD of zero, so the modified Z-score cannot be defined, but I still would like to find the most notable of these categories (you might be wondering why its worth worrying about monthly changes in categories with such low volume, but without getting into detail it can be notable if a category goes from 'mostly zero' to 'notably different from zero' and worth highlighting for subsequent human review).

I was considering having a category separate from the 4 volume based quartiles as described above, where if the MAD = 0 then I simply identify the top N based on 'most recent monthly value's percent change from the pervious N months, but this feels arbitrary and not satisfying.

Would love to get some thoughts on how to handle the MAD = 0 low volume category (and of course any other thoughts as well). If the higher volume categories have a MAD = 0 I don't need to worry about those as the higher volume categories with MAD = 0 are inherently uninteresting, whereas this is not the case with my low volume categories (due to the underlying context).